# Can iOS MDM device send detail internet trafic to server

Tags: ios, mdm, traffic

I want to use iOS MDM and I need detail information about user internet traffic.

I didn't find fullest apple documentation about possible tracking information.

Questions:

1. Can device send information about internet traffic?
2. Information
       about application launch time?
3. Information about visited site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to all 3 questions is no.

However, if the device is supervised, you can configure a global http proxy requiring ALL device comms to go through your proxy. You can then get the information that you need that way.